# jQuery getting img src with variable?

Tags: jquery, html, variables, image

Ive have read like 100+ your topics on this, but no matter what i do i cant get it do like i want to. My problem is i get my `img src="url"` from my `script`. When i alert it it gives me the right input i want, but when i put it in the `attr()` tag i just posts "`imgSrc`" and that in the path to the image. When i hard code the images in the mouseover function it actully works.

Heres my Script

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

            //Hides the images
            $('#imgwrap img').hide();

            //Create variables for Link & Images
            $('a.imgflash').mouseover(function(){
                var linkRel     =   $(this).attr('rel');

                $('#imgwrap img').each(function(i,ele){
                    if($(this).attr('rel') == linkRel) {
                        var imgSrc      =   $(this).attr('src');
                    }               
                });

            });

            //Script that makes images apears
            //Mouseover Script
            $('a.imgflash').mouseover(function(){           
                $('#imgwrap img').attr("src", imgSrc).show();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And heres my HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a rel="demo1" class="imgflash" href="#">demo1</a></li>
    <li><a rel="demo2" class="imgflash" href="#">demo2</a></li>
    <li><a rel="demo3" class="imgflash" href="#">demo3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="imgwrap" style="width:300px; height:300px; overflow:hidden;">
<img rel="demo1" src="images/lux.jpg">
    <img rel="demo2" src="images/cover.jpg">
    <img rel="demo3" src="images/cover2.jpg">
</div>
```

i hope u can help me how to get my Variable "imgSrc" to post like i want to in my mouseover function.

Comment: You have two mouseover handlers for `$('a.imgflash')` - the local variables (eg imgSrc) created in one are not available in the other.  Why two?  From the code I can't even tell what you are trying to do.  Can you explain what you want to happen on mouse over?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
        var imgSrc = '';
        //Create variables for Link & Images
        $('a.imgflash').mouseover(function(){
            var linkRel     =   $(this).attr('rel');

            $('#imgwrap img').each(function(i,ele){
                if($(this).attr('rel') == linkRel) {
                    imgSrc      =   $(this).attr('src');
                }               
            });

        });
```

You need to define the imgSrc variable outside the mouseover event function, because when you are trying to apply it to the `attr`, it does not exist.

You can read more about local/global variables here:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Comment: Isn't ``attr`` deprecated? Use ``prop`` instead.

Comment: unless you're below version 1.6

Comment: Hmm... My bad then... I could swear I had read that somewhere.

Comment: Now im just running in to some more problems, ill post if im getting stuck again :)

Comment: @Nopzen Glad I could help! Usually if an answer has worked for you, you accept it so we know that your issue has been resolved.

Comment: @Christian you probably read [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) page saying *In jQuery 1.3 [@attr] style selectors were removed (they were previously deprecated in jQuery 1.2)*?

Comment: @Nopzen no, accepting can be done with any reputation you probably need (to wait) 10 more **minutes**.

Answer (score 1):

No need for two mouseover handlers. Make your first one do both jobs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Hides the images
    $('#imgwrap img').hide();

    //Create variables for Link & Images
    $('a.imgflash').mouseover(function() {
        var linkRel = $(this).attr('rel');

        $('#imgwrap img').each(function(i, ele) {
            if ($(this).attr('rel') == linkRel) {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Or better yet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Hides the images
    $('#imgwrap img').hide();

    //Create variables for Link & Images
    $('a.imgflash').mouseover(function() {
        var linkRel = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('#imgwrap img[rel="'+linkRel+'"]').show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/J6aLJ/